# OMP Error while using Resnet 50 transfer learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, resnet, transfer-learning

I am trying to use Resnet50 model for my data using transfer learning,
My image data is of size - w-1280 h-960 c-1 I used the following code to preprocess the data to use ResNet50.i Want to find the efficiency of this model for my training and testing data set.
Is code for preprocessing the data correct? or is there any other more efficient way to do it?

Error:` tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] (DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_0' with dtype int32
[[{{node Placeholder/_0}}]]
Epoch 1/10
OMP: Error #34: System unable to allocate necessary resources for OMP thread:
OMP: System error #11: Resource temporarily unavailable
OMP: Hint Try decreasing the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS.

Fatal Python error: Aborted`

```
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50, EfficientNetB0, DenseNet121
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import pandas as pd
import os

os.environ.setdefault( 'OMP_NUM_THREADS', '4')

# Configure TensorFlow session
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))

# Clear TensorFlow session
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

# Define constants
TARGET_SIZE = (224, 224)
TRAIN_DIR = '/home/pavani/output_folder_1/train/'
TEST_DIR = '/home/pavani/output_folder_1/test/'

# Set random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# Define constants
NUM_CLASSES = 2
IMAGE_SIZE = (224, 224)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 10

# Create data generators
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAIN_DIR,
    target_size=TARGET_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=True
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DIR,
    target_size=TARGET_SIZE,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False
)

# Define the models
pretrained_models = [
    ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(TARGET_SIZE[0], TARGET_SIZE[1], 3))]

# Create a DataFrame to store the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Model', 'Accuracy', 'Training Time', 'Trainable Parameters'])

# Train and evaluate each model
for pretrained_model in pretrained_models:
    # Freeze the pretrained layers
    for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    
    # Add custom classification layers
    flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pretrained_model.output)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(flatten)
    cnn_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=pretrained_model.input, outputs=output)
    
    # Compile the model
    cnn_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    # Train the model
    start_time = time.time()  # Start time
    history = cnn_model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        validation_data=test_generator,
        validation_steps=test_generator.samples // BATCH_SIZE
    )
    end_time = time.time()  # End time
    training_time = end_time - start_time
    
    # Evaluate the model
    test_generator.reset()
    y_pred = cnn_model.predict(test_generator)
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    y_true = test_generator.classes
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    

    # Print model summary and number of trainable parameters
    cnn_model.summary()
    trainable_count = int(np.sum([tf.keras.backend.count_params(w) for w in cnn_model.trainable_weights]))
    
    # Append the results to the list
    results_df = results_df.append({
       'Model': pretrained_model.name,
       'Accuracy': accuracy,
       'Training Time': training_time,
       'Trainable Parameters': trainable_count
   }, ignore_index=True)


# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
results_df.to_excel('model_results_3.xlsx', index=False)

# Display the results
print(results_df)
```